# Can I check latest version of play store from another app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

How i can check whether play store is available in the mobile device and whether it is the latest a version or not from my app ,before calling an in app service?

Comment: You cannot check if your app is up to date so easily. But more importantly, you don't have to. The Google Play Store is very fast when it comes to this, as soon as an update is available the user will get a notification. And if the user chooses not to update than that is his decision. Your app needs to work either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the Google Play Services are avaiable on the device like this:

```
int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
switch(errorCode) {
    case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
        // Google Play Services installed and up to date
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
        // Google Play services is missing on this device.
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
        // The installed version of Google Play services is out of date.
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
        // The installed version of Google Play services has been disabled on this device.
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID:
        // The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is not authentic.
        break;

    case ConnectionResult.DATE_INVALID:
        // The device date is likely set incorrectly.
        break;          
}
```

You can also display an appropriate error message if there is a problem:

```
int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
if(GooglePlayServiceUtil.showErrorDialogFragment(errorCode, getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE)) {
    // There was a problem. Error dialog was shown.
} else {
    // Everything is fine. Error dialog was not shown.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public boolean IsPlaystoreInstalled() {
    List<PackageInfo> packages = getApplication().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if (packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.android.vending") ||
            packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.google.market")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yep, i missed a few quotation marks. Why shouldn't it answer the question? It clearly tells you if the PlayStore is available. Why should it be a terrible solution? GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable requires an extra package afaik

Comment: this requires gms which in case you don't need it at all would consume memory. When he's using it anyway, fine, otherwise I would always stick to my solution.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you're not using the Google Play Services SDK it WOULD hurt as the sdk costs memory and usually your aim should be to keep an app as light as possible. If he uses the Service it would be a better solution, otherwise I would stick to my solution.

Comment: I used the first one since i want to know if there any play store update is available or not for that i added google play services too.Both solutions are working